# How can I rearrange $Y =\frac{X}{A+BX}$ to solve for $X$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know Y, A, and B but how can I solve this for X?

$Y =\dfrac{X}{A+BX}$

The $X$ value is the same number if that matters. I used this equation to solve for $A$ but I want to know how I can plug back $Y$, $A$, and B values and solve for $X$.

Mike

Comment: Is this $$Y = \frac{X}{A} + BX,$$ or $$Y = \frac{X}{A + BX}?$$

Comment: Do you mean $y = \frac{x}{a}+bx$? Then $y = (\frac 1 a+b)x$ and then you can divide by the expression in paranthesis.

Comment: Are your variable matrices? if yes, what do you mean by $X/A$ is it  $A^{-1}X$?

Comment: @John, the bottom equation.

Comment: @Michael: Please use parentheses to make such expressions less ambiguous.  What you meant is $Y=X/(A+BX)$.  What you wrote is more likely to be interpreted as $Y=(X/A) + BX$.  (Even better, we can use math typesetting here with horizontal fraction bars.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant: $Y=\frac{X}{A+BX}$

$$Y(A+BX)=X$$
$$YA+YBX=X$$
$$YA=X-YBX$$
$$YA=X(1-YB)$$
$$X=\frac{YA}{1-YB}$$

If you meant: $Y=\frac XA+BX$

$$YA=X+ABX$$
$$YA=X(1+AB)$$
$$X=\frac{YA}{1+AB}$$